# javascript check if a button has been clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a problem with a function that is executing once the page is refreshed and onloaded , i want to  execute  on click event , so there is a button once the user has clicked the button the function should be called and run the code . any ideas ? this is my script

html

```
<input type="submit" id="fff" value="Valider"  Onclick="validation(zero,one,two,three,four)" >
```

javascript

```
function validation(f,a,b,c,d) {
    var str = '';
    var dataString = str;
    $.ajax( {
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/voir/valider/'+f+'/'+a+'/'+b+'/'+c+'/'+d+'/',
        data: dataString,

        success: function(data) {
            $('#shows2').html(data);
        }
    } );
    $('#fff').addClass('hide');
}
```

Comment: **never** use single char variable names

Comment: Doesn't look like you defined `zero`, `one`, `two`, ...

Comment: Could use `.on()` and `.off()`.  You could even use `.one()` and then attach the event listener again from scratch on validation failure.

Comment: @godmode While you generally want to avoid them and give more meaning on variables names.They have their places, so I would not say to **never** use them. For example `for(var i = 0; .. )`.

Comment: i changed these names to strings ones nothing changed , still executing on upload and on refresh !

Comment: I mean convert your parameters to strings (eg. `'zero','one','two','three','four'`) If you look at your console you'll be able to see the error. As far as the function executing on page load and refresh, this is strange because nothing you've shown us here would cause that. I suspect another piece of code trying to run a global function called "validation"? Try changing the your validation function name (and calls to it ) to something like "Guns_Roses_Validation" see the update to my post...

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you might be getting some errors on your parameters, try using strings. The browser probably thinks you have not defined variables of the same name. If your function is being executed automatically it might be that some other code is attempting to call a generic validation function. Try renaming it to Guns_Roses_Validation...

```js
function Guns_Roses_Validation(f,a,b,c,d) {
  console.log("It works!")
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" id="fff" value="Valider"  onclick="Guns_Roses_Validation('zero','one','two','three','four')" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to only allow a single click to the button.

Add a prop (`__clicked`, in this case) to the function that is set once and ignored if set.

```js
function validation(h,o,w,d,y) {

  if(!this.__clicked) {
   this.__clicked = true;
   document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode("clicked"));
  }
 }
```

```html
<input type="submit" id="fff" value="Valider"  onclick='validation("zero","one","two","three","four")' >
```

Also put quotes around the args passed in your click handler if they are string.